# How to remove the action argument from Rails link_to function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

Not sure how to frame this so here goes....

I have the following link_to tag:

```
<%= link_to("My test title",{:controller=>"search", :action=>"for-sale", :title => listing.title, :search_term => search_term, :id=> listing.id}) %>
```

and the following custom route in my routes.rb file:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:title/search_item/:id', :controller=>'search', :action=>'for_sale'
```

which generates a very nice SEO friendly URL:

```
/search/for-sale/sometitle/searchterm/123456
```

How can I remove the :action param from both, the problem is when I take out the :action option & change my link_to tag to:

```
<%= link_to("My test title",{:controller=>"search", :title => listing.title, :search_term => search_term, :id=> listing.id}) %>
```

and my custom route to:

```
map.connect ':controller/:title/search_item/:id', :controller=>'search', :action=>'for_sale'
```

The URL generated is no longer SEO friendly and very ugly:

```
/search?title=test&search_term=test&id=1141409
```

My custom route is redirecting to the correct action within the controller so there is no need for action option to be in the URL. Anytime I remove or rename the :action option to something else - the URL gets "distorted", do you know how I can do this?

Been trying a number of options but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your route `':controller/:title/search_item/:id'` doesn't have `:search_term` parameter, but you are trying to pass it in link_to `:search_term => search_term`

Secondly, if you are always using controller `'search'`, you do not need to pass it as a parameter.

So, your route probably becomes `'search/:title/:search_term/:id'`

Also, try using named routes:

```
map.search 'search/:title/:search_term/:id', :controller=>'search', :action=>'for_sale'

<%= link_to("My test title", search_path(listing.title, search_term, listing.id)) %>
```

**Edit:** optional parameters

You can supply default value for parameters at the end of the route.

So, if you set

```
map.search 'search/:title/:search_term/:id', :controller=>'search', :action=>'for_sale', :id => nil, :search_term => nil
```

You can create url without id: `search_path(listing.title, search_term)`
Or without both id and search_term: `search_path(listing.title)`

If you want to make only `:search_term` optional, put in at the end of the route:

```
map.search 'search/:title/:id/:search_term', :controller=>'search', :action=>'for_sale', :search_term => nil
```

Comment: Thanks for that!

Using the named route though I lose all of the parameters, when I output params.inspect on the for-sale page, the hash contains nothing, they are getting lost somewhere, is their a way to use named routes and still pass the parameters?

Comment: I have found the problem, when one of the parameters is blank or null then none of the parameters get passed to the action, it requires all params to have some value, search_term is a string that may often be blank however....any ideas?

Comment: You can make parameters at the end of the route optional. Added info in the answer.